# How to remove the style attribute when the sortable is dropped?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists on a page with items that may be dragged between them. I'm using jQuery-UI sortable for that functionality. However the style attribute added to the items by jQuery interferes with the style of the borders. I'm trying to remove the style attribute on the `drop` callback, but it seems to fire too early and the sortable adds the style attribute after `removeStyle` is called.

How do I make sure the style attribute is removed after the sortable is done moving the item so that the proper border style shows?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function removeStyle(e, ui) {
    var item = $(ui.draggable)
    item.removeAttr('style')
  }

  $('.drawer, .list').disableSelection();
  $('.drawer').sortable({ connectWith: '.list', tolerance: 'pointer' })
  $('.list').sortable({ connectWith: '.drawer', tolerance: 'pointer' })
  $('.drawer, .list').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'item-over',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop : removeStyle
  })
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahf4hk0j/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor style changes and fire an event when they happen:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutationRecord) {
        console.log('style changed!');
        // removeStyle();
    });    
});

var observationAttributes = { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] };
var target = document.getElementById('yourSortable');
var anotherTarget = document.getElementById('anotherSortable');

// Example of more than one observed element
observer.observe(target, observationAttributes);
observer.observe(anotherTarget, observationAttributes);
```

See here about [`MutationRecords`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationRecord), which I've looped through in the `MutationObserver` callback so each style change has `removeStyle()` fired after it, so the style is definitely removed.